# How can I reverse columns in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with columns A->Z. I would like to reverse the actual columns without having to manually move each column one by one.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does the original data contain formulas? Do you expect to keep those formulas active in the reverse reconfiguration? If the answer to these questions is yes, you may have to do it the hard way. But if you just want to reverse the data, let me know and I'll explain the method. (Even better would be if you shared a link to your sheet or a copy of that sheet, with the link's Share permission set to "Anyone with the link... Editor." Then I can do it directly on your sheet and explain it here more easily.)

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly quick for reversing the columns if it's just data.

Try this

- Add a row above the top row.
- Add numbers to this running from 1 to 26
- Create a new sheet, and name it transpose.
- In it A1=Transpose(range) where range is the occupied area of your original sheet.

At this point each column became a row.

- Select all, and paste special values only
- Right Click column A (the label, not A1) and sort in descending order.
- Create a new sheet name it reversed
- Do the same transform now from Transpose.
- Select all paste values.

File Name version.

Depending on how your formulas work this *might* work.

- Go back to original sheet.
- Copy the area of interst.
- Go to reversed
- Paste special -- formulas.